# Is there an efficient way to calibrate the battery than using some apps?

Tags: battery, battery-life, charging, calibration

Is there an efficient way to calibrate the battery of my tablet in order to prove or disprove the very low battery backup than using some Apps.?

The context is that my tablet is giving a very low battery back up and when I contacted customer care, they are asking me to do a battery calibration by using some app. But, by some other posts in this forum and other help, I was able to understand that Battery Calibration apps does not make a much difference in battery backup improvement or to prove that my battery is really problematic. And there rises this question.

Thanks for your suggestions in advance.

Comment: And did you try that app? Because maybe, it could help, and then you could answer your own question just by doing it?

Comment: the app is on trial. It will take some time to get to know the exact result after some full cycles of discharge and recharge right? So this question is intermediary to that.

Comment: Ah ok, makes sense :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best method is the manual DIY method :D

Step 1: Drain your battery by using it normally until it turns off by itself 
Step 2: Power-on your phone, if it wakes up and you see some power left, do step 1
Step 3: If phone is now drained to the point it can't wake up, Charge it to 100%
Step 4: Once fully charged, power-on phone, and charge it again. Leave it until completely charged
Step 5: Unplug, use, and enjoy.

This makes the phone remember the minimum and maximum voltage, discharge rate and other factors that constitute the battery capacity

WARNING: Do not do this frequently! It will put strain on Li-ion batteries that majority of phones use now. Do this if and only if you are noticing shutdowns on yellow battery bar, cannot charge 100%, and erratic battery capacity display. But still I do this once a month to keep my battery calibrated.

Comment: Actually I had done these steps after doing the recalibration using an app. But, it doesn't show any better improvement in battery backup. So may be my battery is running in bad state or these steps are not enough.

Comment: If your tablet is a year old or more, and you're a heavy user, then it might be the battery that needs replacement. Are you experiencing fast battery drain?

Comment: My tablet is just only 4 months old

Comment: Then the problem is not with the battery. Have you recently installed some app(s) before the problem manifested? If yes, try freezing or temporarily uninstalling that app, then use ur tab normally for a day and check the battery level

Comment: probably I am misguiding you. This is not an issue which I started facing recently. This was almost like this from start. But, my customer care people told me that it was due usage of calling facility in my tab. I didn't investigated about it much then. Now without any connectivity also it was giving only very less backup. So, I started with all these investigations so that I can claim my warranty full proof :)

Comment: I see. So tablet already has a faulty battery meter. You can use android's built-in battery graph in settings or other battery logging apps to convince them of consistently low readings

Comment: that is a good suggestion. I will try some other battery logging app as well. Do you have any suggestions on this?

Comment: @RinoTom: JuicePlotter + BetterBatteryStats

Comment: @RinoTom You may find this article useful http://www.blogtechnika.com/optimize_battery_life_on_android/

Comment: @forums One remark: LiIo batteries don't take it well being fully drained, it shortens their life-time. So I'd for sure skip step 2; it should be more than enough if it is below 5% of its charge. Reference: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lithium-ion#Battery_life): *Li+ batteries last longer if not deeply discharged (depleted) before recharging. The smaller the depth of discharge, the longer the battery will last.*

Comment: @Izzy My phone went from 11% to 10% and then 1 second later to 0% and shut off, so I'm trying to recalibrate.  I did step 2 twice, each time I saw the logo for about 8 seconds before it shut off.  The third time it actually stayed on about two seconds longer.  If the gauge is *really* off (i.e. since it dropped nearly instantly from 10% to 0%), any chance I might have to repeatedly make it auto turn off to reach 5%?

Comment: @Michael there might be apps to achieve that (I think e.g. of [tag:tasker]). But honestly, I rarely let my devices get that low. Usually they go to the charger long before they're down at 20% (i.e. even before the battery low alert fires).