# Battery getting charged with ultra speed and continuous at 1%charge for more than 9 hrs

Tags: battery, battery-life, charging, sony-xperia-neo-v

My neo v battery getting charged with in ten min from 0 to 100 percentage( Exponential growth graph ) with ultra speed and getting discharged to 1%( it also give alert showing last 1% left, keep charging)  with in 3 or 4 hrs. The last 1% charging is left for 9 to 10 hrs even then its not getting switched off.. Again i started to keep charging , charging process is started but Charging percentage shown 1% for the first 5 to 8 min. Later i removed my battery from neo v and kept again.. later after switching it on , it showed 46% already charged.. Again i kept charging , remaining 54 percent charged with in 10 min..

If we think there is a problem with battery.. The last 1% should not come for 9 to 10 hrs... and should not become 100% within 10 min.. And I also checked with one of my friend Neo V replacing my battery in thier mobile.. it worked normally and shown correct percentage of charging left  Similarly i kept their battery which is of 46% charge left in my mobile.. then it showed a decrease of 1% for every 1min.. But when i placed my friend battery in his mobile.. it showing 46% as it is which was earlier seen. So surely there is no problem with battery.

According to me the issue is with the battery indicator which is misleading me.. As it showing wrong percentages.

I read some of the blogs related to this issue.. Battery indicator is not a hardware related thing.. its a back ground service that is technically always running but is essentially always sleeping and using basically no system resources (because it doesn't do any polling -- it just sleeps and waits to be notified by the OS when something changes), then when the battery charge (or plugged-in status) changes, the system wakes it up and tells it what the new battery charge (and status) is. Then it takes just a few milliseconds to change its icon to reflect the current charge (and status) and goes back to sleep. So i think there is no hardware issue..

I also did software repair from sony pc companion.. But there is no change..

I am facing this issue for the first time from yesterday morning ..

Can u pls say what's happening to my battery.. And I bought this mobile last year March 4th 2012 from "The Mobile Store".. 1 year completed.. I have extended warranty of 1 year.

Is it a software problem or Hardware problem.

Is there any solution for this?

Comment: [Try these steps](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/40042/28820)

Comment: Just to clarify: when you switched batteries with your friends phone, both batteries/devices indicated normal behaviour? Or did a) your device stick with the same error or b) his device (with your battery) showed the same problems? I didn't understand that correctly. With b), the charging processor in the battery might be "mad", with a) it also might be some electronics issue. In both cases I'd explain so to the service, asking for a replacement battery (b) or phone (a). If neither a nor b, I'd simply leave your batt with your friend's and keep his :-)

Answer (score 1):

Try calibrating your battery, it helped me a lot. I had the same issue, 100%, immediately to low 7% again 70%, like that. Calibration means, it just removes battery_stats.bin from your /system/ and OS will regenerate another one. This will remove any miscalculations. After calibrating, it's recommended to drain your phone to the fullest and charge them back to 100%. If you have rooted your phone, this is one right way. :)

Comment: If you have not rooted your phone, having it discharge completely and then recharging it fully should assist with making the calibration better.