# How to calibrate a new Nexus 5 battery that's higher capacity than original?

Tags: battery, charging, nexus-5, 5.0-lollipop, calibration

Just got a KBTEL battery that's 3800 mAh compared to the original 2300 mAh nexus battery. I charged it dead overnight, and now its been running for more than 7 hours and the capacity shows below 5% for an hour now but its not dying. How do i get the battery meter to show the actual range? The system still detects a 2300 mAh battery.

Comment: Not a dupe, but [general method to calibrate the battery on Android](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/39746/is-there-an-efficient-way-to-calibrate-the-battery-than-using-some-apps)

Answer (score 1):

[Battery Calibration](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1024867) thread on XDA forums. [Download](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nema.batterycalibration) from the Play Store.

---

## Description°

**Requirements**: Android 2.1+ | Root permissions

Calibration needs to be done after flashing a new ROM, but you can calibrate any time you think your battery is miscalibrated. This program does it by removing the batterystats.bin system file. The OS generates a new clean batterystats file soon, thus any fake information from the previous ROM is removed.
It's suggested, but not necessary, to let the phone fully discharge after calibration, then charged to 100% without break.
The app shows your actual battery status, and only allows you to start the calibration (i.e. removes the file) when it's fully charged, unless you force earlier calibration.

- °copied from https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nema.batterycalibration

Comment: Deleting the batterystats.bin does not help calibrate the battery. that was a myth and misconception, which was [debunked by Google Android Engineer](https://plus.google.com/u/0/105051985738280261832/posts/FV3LVtdVxPT)

Comment: @Ryan - that might be so, but it did straighten out the mis-calibration problem that I was having. Reboots did help, nor did cache/dalvik wipings. I have wiped battery stats from recovery as well, with excellent results. Go figure. :)

Comment: @Ryan - I read through the debunk link, nice points, but she doesn't provide any reference/fact/resource to prove her statement other than her own admission. After that the comments seem to start to drift.

Comment: The fact is she is an engineer on Android, the comments are from people that do not work on Android. This information is also 2 years old. Just search for "batterystats.bin" you will see the same information. The batterystats info is cleared when you unplug from a full charge. What you experienced is the placebo effect.

Comment: I don't have root permission. Isn't there a simple solution? But I'm on the new battery for the 2nd day today, and now it seems to be working right. I see more than 12 hours battery life expected which is what i expected from the new battery.

Comment: Well, actually it does not calibrate the battery. As the article say, the file is deleted every time you charge to 100%. That's the way to recalibrate your phone! Every time you go to 0% to 100% the battery calibrates.