# LG G2 wrong battery size report

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, battery

I get a LG G2 with Android 5.0.2, and when I check the battery it says that the capacity is 1900mAh instead 3000mAh that is the real amount of battery capacity.
I make a little research and found that is a xml configuration file error and in Kitkat didn't happen, but I can't find the solution to this.

Does somebody know how to fix this?

Comment: How do you check it?

Comment: By two different applications Phone Tester and AIDA64, both works OK on Defy MB525 and MOTO E XT1527. I found some info in http://forum.xda-developers.com/lg-g2/general/official-lg-g2-android-5-0-lolipop-t3046813/page80  but not the solution.

Comment: Related [Where are the battery capacity files located?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/145263/131553) for explanation and one possible way indicated in my [answer here](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/135136/131553)

Comment: @beeshyams The cellphone is in factory status, and never make a complete cycle discharge/charge. 3C ToolBox shows 3000mAh and show 19mA of consumption, no matter if the screen at low or full brightness. I will wait until the battery goes to 10% and recharge it and see if something change.