# Calculate phone's battery capacity

Tags: battery

I found this product ([check the product here](http://www.amazon.in/detector-voltmeter-ammeter-capacity-voltage/dp/B06XJGDCBN?tag=googinhydr18418-21&tag=googinkenshoo-21&ascsubtag=065f9406-95d9-4e30-bdb6-7baa5c10a194)) on Amazon. Can this product be able to calculate the power of my phone's battery if connected to the USB port of my phone? I want to check the original capacity apart from what the manufacturer or any file on Android says.

Will the phone's USB port output the required power for this function?

I tried 3C Battery Monitor, the app says it's 1580mAh, but its 2100mAh in websites and on the battery (it's a phone by a well-known manufacturer, but I don't want to say it here because I don't want the answers to be focussed to the phone make or the model).

Comment: Do note that battery capacity will wear down over time. The 3C app likely observes and reports the current full capacity, while the website gives factory (new) capacity.

Comment: Is the calculated capacity be trusted? I found here (http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/145263/where-are-the-battery-capacity-files-located) that the app uses two sources, one of which is the Android APIs. Android APIs can be edited if there's a root access, so it I modify it, does the app find the actual capacity?

Comment: What about the device I've provided in Amazon (http://www.amazon.in/detector-voltmeter-ammeter-capacity-voltage/dp/B06XJGDCBN?tag=googinhydr18418-21&tag=googinkenshoo-21&ascsubtag=065f9406-95d9-4e30-bdb6-7baa5c10a194)?

Comment: Tested again. This time, it is 2333mAh for the same phone.

Comment: Then I'd say that the app itself reads inaccurately. Refer to @beeshyams 's answer. P.S. Personally I have a small in-line meter (shown in [this question](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/167474/battery-capacity-wear-down-and-its-relationship-to-charging-practices)) to measure battery capacity through fully charging, though I admit that's not for everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am basing this answer on the concerns expressed in comments and your main question

- Firstly, there are many ways of measuring mAH of batteries with different results, so the device manufacturer is the best person to ask this question- it claims to read *battery capacity* but **how it measures** is not known from the product description. There are different methods for hardware measurements with varying results ( a subject in itself ). See this to get a feel

[How to measure capacity of a Lithium-ion battery - Electrical Engineering Stack Exchange](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/18612/how-to-measure-capacity-of-a-lithium-ion-battery)

- Next, as covered in the answer here 
  [Where are the battery capacity files located?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/145263/131553), it is quite possible to amend the values on a rooted device but ultimately it depends on the app which chooses from **where to read** the values from
- Your main concern, it appears to me is to know the true mAh of battery which is covered here using the 3C app , in my answer [How to determine maximum capacity of a battery in mAh? - received fake battery](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/96629)

Answer (score 0):

You could try the accubattery app, it is known to give a somewhat accurate reading. It also gives other quite interesting information about your battery.

Comment: It's nice to know about the app, but the device runs on Android Jelly Bean, which is not supported by AccuBattery.

Comment: I have one of those devices for my custom built race drone, I use it to check voltages so I am not sure how accurate it is on mAh. I dont think its necessary to buy such device for your use case, the apps are accurate enough.

Comment: Thanks for the review about the device. But I am concerned about the Android battery API files which might be accessed and modified if there is root permission. What if I modify the file to, like 3000mAh, do the apps provide exact value for capacity?

Comment: @Neeraj I dont quite understand what you mean by that however most of the battery calculating apps use algorithms that measure the mAh going into the phone while charging, and how long it takes to increase per percent. There isnt a single android file that tells you the true capacity of your battery after wear.

Comment: Apps are inaccurate. I've been testing for four days where I get four different readings - 1580mAh, 2333mAh, 2335mAh and 864mAh. What I mean in the previous comment was "In the question here http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/145263/where-are-the-battery-capacity-files-located by beeshyams, it says about the file where battery capacity information is stored. In my findings, not only battery, but even the CPU clock speed are stored in files in /sys/. So, may be, the apps are accessing those files to get mAh?"

Comment: @Neeraj Perhaps some do, however I know that accubattery in particular follows the method I have described. Yes they are inaccurate, but they give some level of accuracy on your battery capacity. (Also they are more accurate if you charge from 0-100%) I do know of apps that get cpu frequency from files in /sys/ and they have been pretty accurate as far as i know